# EmguCV конвертация в Bitmap

Tags: c#, emgucv

Надо конвертировать `Image<Bgr, byte>` в `Bitmap`.
Погуглил, во всех примерах делают так:

```cs
pictureBoxOutput.Image = mat.ToImage<Bgr, byte>().Flip(Emgu.CV.CvEnum.FlipType.Horizontal).Bitmap;
```

А у меня вот... Не содержит определения Bitmap
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: [Emgu.CV (in Emgu.CV.dll) Version: 2.4.2.1777](https://emgu.com/wiki/files/2.4.2/document/Index.html), а у вас что за библиотека и какая версия? Еще версию дотнета скажите.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы использовали пример для старой версии **Emgu.CV**

[`Image<TColor, TDepth> Class` Emgu.CV.Platform.NetStandard Version: 4.5.4.4788](https://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/4.5.4/document/html/T_Emgu_CV_Image_2.htm)

Согласно документации версии 4.5.4, вам подойдет вот этот метод.

```cs
public static Bitmap ToBitmap<TColor, TDepth>(this Image<TColor, TDepth> image)
```

> Convert this image into Bitmap, the pixel values are copied over to the Bitmap

```cs
pictureBoxOutput.Image = mat.ToImage<Bgr, byte>()
    .Flip(Emgu.CV.CvEnum.FlipType.Horizontal)
    .ToBitmap();
```